# Where can the Ubuntu 20.04 release candidate be found?

Tags: downloads

I've checked the obvious places, including https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseSchedule (which states the release candidate should have gone up yesterday) and http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/20.04/ . A pointer to a BitTorrent file/magnet link would be great but http download is fine - I'm looking to install it on a new system, not upgrade.

Comment: 20.04 has not been released yet ;-)

Comment: @Pilot6 I addressed this by editing my question - thanks!

Comment: Release candidates are off-topic at this site.

Comment: Well, still we're here to help people.. So http://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04/ubuntu-20.04-beta-desktop-amd64.iso (the whole list is on this page: http://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04/)

Comment: Thanks @kanehekili I already have the beta, but since it'll be a while before I'm able to install I figured I'd wait for the RC.

Comment: @Pilot6 you yourself noted 20.04 was not yet released, and then you participated in closing it as an "end of life release" question - is that right?

Comment: @airbornemihir  I've installed beta and it will be updated until it is a "full" version. So you'll gain only some updates... Btw for a "beta" that image seems pretty mature.

Comment: I participated in closing for another reason. `problems specific to development version of Ubuntu` are off-topic as well.

Comment: The 'beta' is old now, it was current for less than 48 hours, if you want the latest you should use the daily (containing all upgrades since then; HUGE changes occurred early this week due to re-builds making beta very old). http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/

Comment: @guiverc I've just installed 185 packages, which took about 10 mins. So you're right, my "beta" was really old, but these 10 minutes changed everything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't find it [on the web](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/) you can do `sudo do-release-upgrade` 
and that should work if not you can also do `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` and you will be upgraded to the latest version of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS might be a beta possibly if you add the `-d` at the end so don't use it on any critical systems.

Comment: Will `sudo do-release-upgrade` work for pointer releases also.